# How can I set an S3 Bucket Policy using the ruby gem aws-s3?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I'm trying to set an S3 bucket policy using the aws-s3 gem.  However, I'm open to other ways of doing it.  I have a raw json string representing the policy.

I've been trying for a while.  I know I can do it, just having one of those days.

If anyone knows how, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend using the aws-sdk gem (disclaimer, I am a contributor):

```
require 'aws-sdk'

AWS.config(:access_key_id => '...', :secret_access_key => '...')
AWS::S3.new.buckets['bucket-name'].policy = json_policy
```